# Installing Chrome Extension via CLI

Tags: linux, command-line, google-chrome, automation

I automated most of my Linux setup with Ansible, however, there is one big issue I do face whenever applying it onto new machines. Chrome is being installed automatically, but it does not come with any extensions I may need. So I have to add them by hand, which is a huge pain.

Is there a way to install extensions via CLI for Google-Chrome or Chromium? I'd rather not do it via Google-Account syncs if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but this looks like a promising script resource
https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-install-google-chrome-extensions-though-terminal/

Contents from the link:
Here is the script, you gonna need extension ids, they can be found in the address bar when you go to the details of the extension on the market or at chrome://extensions. The script will also install chrome if it is not installed, remove the middle part if that's not needed.

1. Save this script to the `install-chrome.sh` file:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   install_chrome_extension () {
     preferences_dir_path="/opt/google/chrome/extensions"
     pref_file_path="$preferences_dir_path/$1.json"
     upd_url="https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"
     mkdir -p "$preferences_dir_path"
     echo "{" > "$pref_file_path"
     echo "  \"external_update_url\": \"$upd_url\"" >> "$pref_file_path"
     echo "}" >> "$pref_file_path"
     echo Added \""$pref_file_path"\" ["$2"]
   }

   if ! which "google-chrome" ; then
     wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub \
     | sudo apt-key add -
     echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' \
     | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
   else
     echo Chrome already installed
   fi

   install_chrome_extension "cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb" "adblock plus"
   install_chrome_extension "fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi" "react dev tools"
   install_chrome_extension "anmidgajdonkgmmilbccfefkfieajakd" "save pinned tabs"
   install_chrome_extension "dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb" "vimium"
   ```
2. Run

   ```sh
   sudo bash install-chrome.sh
   ```
3. Restart chrome.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. You can include the relevant information by [edit]ing your answer here.